# Paperclip config conflicting with AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, paperclip, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using Paperclip in my Rails 5.1 app and have the standard config in my development.rb and production.rb:

```
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
    storage: :s3,
    s3_credentials: {
      bucket: ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET'),
      access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
      secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
      s3_region: ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION'),
    }
  }
```

I'm storing the ENV variables in `application.yml` via Figaro gem.

This is fine, but I'm now trying to upload my app to a new AWS Elastic Beanstalk app and I'm having the build fail.  Having spent the last 3 or so hours looking through all the logs and trying various changes, I've narrowed the failure down to the fact I think Beanstalk is reading the Paperclip ENVs and is getting confused.

From the logs:

```
  rake aborted!
<<<
  /var/app/ondeck/config/environments/production.rb:97:in `fetch'
  /var/app/ondeck/config/environments/production.rb:97:in `block in <top (required)>'
  /var/app/ondeck/config/environments/production.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  /var/app/ondeck/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.4.3/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
  /opt/rubies/ruby-2.4.3/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
  Tasks: TOP => environment
```

and `config/environments/production.rb:97` equates the below value from my Paperclip config:

```
access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
```

I can't seem to find any items online that would help resolve this.

Any ideas?

Could I use the same IAM user for both so the ENV values match?

Comment: Please confirm your `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` exists in your config....

Comment: Also for elastic-beanstalk you can set the env variables in the sofware configuration of your env on your AWS dashboard

Comment: `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` does not exist in my beanstalk config as it hadn't been required.  It's in my local app for the S3 config for Paperclip.  If I do add it to Beanstalk, no doubt I'll need to create a new IAM user that has access to both the paperclip bucket, and my app bucket?

Comment: Does it exist in your figaro env varibles...?

Comment: yes it does....

Comment: Because what I would suggest is to set the env varibles on the elastic-beanstalk environment  so that the eb deploy is able to access them during deploy because this is what might be causing the issue.trying to read the all those env variables and being unable to get them

Comment: hed over to your `environment` -> `youll see a configuration option (title - Modify software -)`-> `then add your env varibles below in the fields under - environments - `

Comment: Going through and adding all the variables from Paperclip into Beanstalk has fixed it. Feels kinda wrong though.

Comment: Elastic beanstalk kind of has its own rules :)

Comment: added an answer incase someone runs into a similar problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164187/discussion-between-iamcaleberic-and-simon-cooper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the paperclip S3 `environment` variables to your `Elastic Beanstalk Environment`

> **How?**

Head over to your specific `Environment`

Select `Configuration`

In `Configuration overview` select `Software` tile

At the very bottom you'll see a form section `Environment properties`

Add `key` and `value` data for your variables

Save and wait for your environment to `update`.

**Read more:** [Elastic Beanstalk Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-console.html#environments-console-configuration)